# Server failed to authenticate the request in Visual Studio Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request)

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

When running a code in VS, the API is returning the error as below. Our web app is on Azure.

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:1df942bf-f01e-0071-2a98-cb0e79000000
> Time:2023-08-10T14:39:47.6404514Z
> Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
> ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed
>
> Additional Information:
> AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Mon, 05 Dec 2022 10:48:52 GMT] - Expiry [Fri, 28 Jul 2023 18:48:52 GMT] - Current [Thu, 10 Aug 2023 14:39:47 GMT]
>
> Content:
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error>\
> AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:1df942bf-f01e-0071-2a98-cb0e79000000
> Time:2023-08-10T14:39:47.6404514Z</Message>
> \ Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Mon, 05 Dec 2022 10:48:52 GMT] - Expiry [Fri, 28 Jul 2023 18:48:52 GMT] - Current [Thu, 10 Aug 2023 14:39:47 GMT]
> </AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
>
> Headers:
> x-ms-request-id: 1df942bf-f01e-0071-2a98-cb0e79000000
> x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
> Content-Length: 544
> Content-Type: application/xml
> Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2023 14:39:46 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

We tried creating new web app and the same error throws up with certificate not valid, suggesting to change the header. We haven't changed anything on the web app, it all worked till 28th July.

Comment: Could you please share the code ?

Comment: This issue is Fixed. We found the expiry date of SAS blob was set to 28th July 2023 in the service config file. We removed the expiry date in the connection string, and we don’t see any error. See last phrase where it quotes" 2023-07-28T18:48:52." this was removed.
TableEndpoint=https://jsndstoreuswsaz.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=2021-06-08&amp;ss=b&amp;srt=sco&amp;sp=rwdlaciytfx&amp;se=2023-07-28T18:48:52Z&amp;st=2022-12-05T10:48:52Z

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer, it will be helpful for others who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is Fixed. We found the expiry date of SAS blob was set to 28th July 2023 in the service config file. We removed the expiry date in the connection string, and we don’t see any error. See last phrase where it quotes" 2023-07-28T18:48:52." this was removed. TableEndpoint=jsndstoreuswsaz.table.core.windows.net/…